# Why does PHP throw an error when an expression is passed as the index of a numeric array within a closure

Tags: php, arrays

I have a development environment running Apache2, PHP7.4 on Ubuntu and a production server running Apache2, PHP7.2 on Ubuntu. The following code works well on my development environment but fails on production with the error `[2020-07-25 13:00:16] production.ERROR: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ']' {"exception":"[object] (ParseError(code: 0): syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ']' at /path/to/file.php:133)`. This is the line that is failing: `$month = $months[$months[$i - 1]];`.

```
function myFunction(){
    $months = ['jan','feb','mar','apr','may','jun','jul','aug','sep','oct','nov','dec'];
    return (function()use($months){
            $ret = [];
            $i = 1;
            while($i < 13)
            {
                $month = $months[$i - 1];
                // some more code that updates $ret ...
                $i++;
            }
            return $ret;
        })();
}
```

I will appreciate any ideas on why this is failing.

Comment: `$ret` is never used and you don't have the months as keys anywhere. Looks like it should be `$month = $months[$i - 1];`.

Comment: Thanks @user3783243, There was a typo there. I have edited my question to reflect what the code I am having issues with. **$ret** is updated within the while loop and gets returned by the closure.

Comment: The code you've presented doesn't update `$ret` and doesn't produce errors, https://3v4l.org/p9WvJ.

Comment: Thanks @user3783243 for looking into this. I actually removed the part of the code that updates **$ret ** for brevity. The code works perfectly on my local development environment but fails with the given error on my production environment. I can share the full details if necessary.

Comment: Unable to reproduce on PHP 7.2. Please confirm that the sample code above (not your full version) produces said error on your production server.

Comment: @MarkusAO I have run it on production and realized that it does not work when the function definition is within a trait, which is what I was doing. So I removed it from within the trait and it worked!! I wonder what the issue is with the trait. Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest you create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) specimen that fails on your test server and share it. I'm testing the following, error-free: [Class & Trait & Your Function on PHP 7.2](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6fcddebf7998cf7f5adf110d719c4949ee68d60d).

Comment: Thanks @MarkusAO. I am going to create a MCVE specimen and update my question here.